# Connect to mysql in a docker container from the host

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

**In a nutshell**

I want to run mysql in a docker container and connect to it from my host. So far, the best I have achieved is:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

**More details**

I'm using the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-server

# Ensure we won't bind to localhost only
RUN grep -v bind-address /etc/mysql/my.cnf > temp.txt \
  && mv temp.txt /etc/mysql/my.cnf

# It doesn't seem needed since I'll use -p, but it can't hurt
EXPOSE 3306

CMD /etc/init.d/mysql start && tail -F /var/log/mysql.log
```

In the directory where there is this file, I can succesfully build the image and run it with:

```
> docker build -t my-image .
> docker run -d -p 12345:3306 my-image
```

When I attach to the image, it seems to work just fine:

```
# from the host
> docker exec -it <my_image_name> bash

#inside of the container now
$ mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
[...]
```

However I don't have that much success from the host:

```
> mysql -P 12345 -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

**Even more details**

- I've seen that there's a question which [looks like mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25069860/1796345). However, it isn't the same (and it doesn't have any answers anyway)
- I've seen that there are images [dedicated to mysql](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-mysql), but I didn't have more success with them
- My `grep -v` may feel weird. Admittedly, there may be cleaner way to do it. But when I attach my image, I can observe it actually worked as expected (ie: removed the `bind-address`). And I can see in the container `/var/log/mysql/error.log`:

> Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
> - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
> Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.

Comment: Probably not so dumb. I stumbled upon this for the 10th time now and finally got the time to try it out at home.

Comment: NOTE: some people may end up here, and want to connect to a mysql image run in docker, but the port isn't exposed. When you run it using the `docker run` command, make sure you open the port, like so, `docker run -p 3306:3306 ...` or you wont be able to connect. Of course this can be done in a Dockerfile too, but you don't need a custom docker image to do this!

Comment: A note for people who, like me, store their dev credentials in a .my.cnf file and then wonder why they cannot connect with root: The password from .my.cnf will be used even when specifying `-p` without a value. To avoid that, `--no-defaults` worked for me. In full, `mysql --no-defaults --protocol=tcp -uroot -p`.

Comment: Similar: [*Use JDBC on host OS to connect to MySQL server running in a Docker Desktop container*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77738571/642706)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

If you use "127.0.0.1" instead of localhost mysql will use tcp method and you should be able to connect container with:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the case.  Not downvoting because I'm not 100% sure, but in my experience localhost and 127.0.0.1 always attempt to use a socket unless you add --protocol=tcp

Comment: I can verify that once i changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 and removed the protocol flag, it worked the same

Comment: I think this is the short and best answer ;)

Comment: Might be short but it's not the answer, given that TCP is the slower method to communicate with mysql. (more cpu and higher latency)

Comment: @John you are right, it's slower but it does exist.  Of course you can share /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock  between host and container.

Comment: That's what I'd recommend for any higher duty DB. it's as simple as "-v socketfile.sock" and then mysql --socket /path/file.sock  without polluting the tcp/ip stack.

Comment: Can confirm that using `127.0.0.1` for the host property fixes the error but using `localhost` leaves me with the same problem. On OSX 10.13.6

Comment: I'm using Rails and I had trouble running `rake db:setup` from outside docker connecting to the mysql database.  Specifying the host `127.0.0.1` solves it.

Comment: Note just for other stupids like myself: `docker ps` to list all containers; copy CONTAINER_ID of your DB container; `docker exec -it {CONTAINER_ID} bash`; copy DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD from docker-compose.yaml; `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u {DB_USERNAME } -p` and type in `{DB_PASSWORD}`. Also `show databases;`, `use {DATABASE_NAME}`; `show tables;`, if you need.

Answer (score 354):

If your Docker MySQL host is running correctly you can connect to it from local machine, but you should specify host, port and protocol like this:

```sh
mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root
```

Change 3306 to port number you have forwarded from Docker container (in your case it will be 12345).

Because you are running MySQL inside Docker container, socket is not available and you need to connect through TCP. Setting "--protocol" in the mysql command will change that.

Comment: Can you clarify why the mysql socket is not available? Your command works, but I'm wondering if there's a way to mount the mysql socket to the host from the container.

Comment: I am not an expert in Unix communication, but from what I understand socket is a connection represented as a file. Since socket file is not shared between Docker container and host machine MySQL client cannot use one from inside of the Docker container. 
To connect to the MySQL server inside Docker container from host machine you could:

1. Set MySQL server to put socket in the specified place `--socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`
2. Mount this file outside of the Docker container
3. Specify path to socket in MySQL client with `--socket=/host/mysql.sock`

Comment: @maniekq Great comment! But did you verify all your three possibilities? Do they all really work?

Comment: After I long struggle I found this golden answer, `--protocol=tcp` finally made the connection work. Thanks @maniekq for both the nice answer and your explanation on sockets via your comment!

Comment: It should not be the accepted answer, since he explicitly states that he has no idea of UNIX file communication.

Comment: I believe that if you use the host `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` then you will be using the TCP stack instead of the unix socket, thus making the `--protocol` flag unnecessary.

Comment: This worked for me. I just needed to add `-p` at the end so MySQL will ask for a password.

Comment: works fine without `protocol`, basically what i did is `mysql -h localhost -P 12345 -u root -p password`

Comment: I did not have to set the protocol, works fine without protocol. But does mysql know to connect to container as what we are saying is localhost but the IP of the container could be different. Also the host and the container are not on the same network I presume?

Comment: For other dumb-dumbs like myself, I gave detailed commands in a comment to @VasiliPascal's answer.

Comment: For me, using either `--protocol=tcp` _or_ `-h 127.0.0.1` did the trick. (I also needed the `-p` flag, bc I ran my container with `-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=`. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to restore a database from a file on my host to an instance running inside a docker container using DBeaver. DBeaver could connect correctly, but the restore kept failing complaining about the socket. I added --protocol=tcp to the arguments input for the restore task and it worked!

Answer (score 54):

I recommend checking out docker-compose.  Here's how that would work:

Create a file named, docker-compose.yml that looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:

  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.1.19
    ports:
      - 8083:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wp
```

Next, run:

> $ docker-compose up

Notes:

- For latest mariadb image tag see https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/

Now, you can access the mysql console thusly:

> $ mysql  -P 8083 --protocol=tcp -u root -p

```
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 5.5.5-10.1.19-MariaDB-1~jessie mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Notes:

- You can pass the -d flag to run the mysql/mariadb container in detached/background mode.
- The password is "wp" which is defined in the docker-compose.yml file.
- Same advice as maniekq but full example with docker-compose.

Comment: `--protocol=tcp` fixed everything for me. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I had same issue as in topic but after using --protocol=tcp it fixed. I thought something was wrong with docker network.

Comment: You're welcome @tiago-elias.  As a heads up, I hope to release another chapter, "Deep Data Analysis," in my book soon:  https://leanpub.com/dataengineeringhandbook

Comment: Not setting the IP address explicitly did the trick for me, thank you!

Answer (score 22):

The simple method is to share the mysql unix socket to host machine. Then connect through the socket

Steps:

- Create shared folder for host machine eg: `mkdir /host`
- Run docker container with volume mount option `docker run -it -v /host:/shared <mysql image>`.
- Then change mysql configuration file `/etc/my.cnf` and change socket entry in the file to `socket=/shared/mysql.sock`
- Restart MySQL service `service mysql restart` in docker
- Finally Connect to MySQL servver from host through the socket `mysql -u root --socket=/host/mysql.sock`. If password use -p option

Comment: Do you have to do this if the MySQL client is in another container ?

Comment: I don't know that. I opted this method because tcp-ip port method didn't work for me. If you are using two containers for server and client, you can share a common directory to both containers and use Unix socket to connect to MySQL.

Comment: The answer to my question is no when I use docker-compose with a link on the containers.

Comment: This is working but connection using host is not

Answer (score 20):

OK. I finally solved this problem.  Here follows my solution used in https://sqlflow.org/sqlflow.

### The Complete Solution

To make the demo self-contained, I moved all necessary code to https://github.com/wangkuiyi/mysql-server-in-docker.

### The Key to the Solution

I don't use the official image on DockerHub.com https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server.  Instead, I made my own by installing MySQL on Ubuntu 18.04.  This approach gives me the chance to start mysqld and **bind it to 0.0.0.0 (all IPs)**.

For details, please refer to [these lines](https://github.com/wangkuiyi/mysql-server-in-docker/blob/8a8fce25fd488a4b0c2fe7b18ed8551107235d12/start.bash#L3-L8) in my GitHub repo.

```sh
SQLFLOW_MYSQL_HOST=${SQLFLOW_MYSQL_HOST:-0.0.0.0}

echo "Start mysqld ..."
sed -i "s/.*bind-address.*/bind-address = ${SQLFLOW_MYSQL_HOST}/" \
    /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
service mysql start
```

### To Verify My Solution

1. Git clone the aforementioned repo.

   ```sh
   git clone https://github.com/wangkuiyi/mysql-server-in-docker
   cd mysql-server-in-docker
   ```
2. Build the MySQL server Docker image

   ```sh
   docker build -t mysql:yi .
   ```
3. Start MySQL server in a container

   ```sh
   docker run --rm -d -p 23306:3306 mysql:yi
   ```
4. Install the MySQL client on the host, if not yet.  I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on the host (my workstation), so I use `apt-get`.

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install -y mysql-client
   ```
5. Connect from the host to the MySQL server running in the container.

   ```sh
   mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 23306 --user root -proot
   ```

#### Connect from Another Container on the Same Host

We can run MySQL client from even another container (on the same host).

```sh
docker run --rm -it --net=host mysql/mysql-server mysql \
   -h 127.0.0.1 -P 13306 -u root -proot
```

#### Connect from Another Host

On my iMac, I install the MySQL client using Homebrew.

```sh
brew install mysql-client
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"
```

Then, I can access the above Ubuntu host (192.168.1.22).

```sh
mysql -h 192.168.1.22 -P 13306 -u root -proot
```

#### Connect from a Container Running on Another Host

I can even run MySQL client in a container running on the iMac to connect to the MySQL server in a container on my Ubuntu workstation.

```sh
docker run --rm -it --net=host mysql/mysql-server mysql \
    -h 192.168.1.22 -P 13306 -u root -proot
```

### A Special Case

In the case that we run MySQL client and server in separate containers running on the same host -- this could happen when we are setting up a CI, we don't need to build our own MySQL server Docker image.  Instead, we can use the `--net=container:mysql_server_container_name` when we run the client container.

To start the server

```sh
docker run --rm -d --name mysql mysql/mysql-server
```

To start the client

```sh
docker run --rm -it --net=container:mysql mysql/mysql-server mysql \
 -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -proot
```

Answer (score 11):

You should inspect the IP address assigned to the running container, and ther connect to that host:

`docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <container name or id>`

than you can connect with:

`mysql -h <IP provided by inspect command> -P <port> -u <user> -p <db name>`

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-and-using-mariadb-via-docker/#connecting-to-mariadb-from-outside-the-container

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I was looking for to connect to db via mysql client.

Comment: That IP address is not generally useful, especially using systems like Docker Desktop, and you do not need to look it up.

Answer (score 10):

if you running docker under docker-machine?

execute to get ip:

```
docker-machine ip <machine>
```

returns the ip for the machine and try connect mysql:

```
mysql -h<docker-machine-ip>
```

Comment: Solved in Docker-Toolbox :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

In your terminal run: `docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash`
Then: `mysql`

Comment: if u run on windows, u cannot run this on git-bash, but on cmd ms-dos

Comment: The question asks how to connect from the host.  The problem description states that they're able to connect from within the container.

Answer (score 6):

- `docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass --name sql-db -p 3306:3306 mysql`
- `docker exec -it sql-db bash`
- `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: that will end with `ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded`

Comment: @Enerccio Could you try again?

Answer (score 5):

I do this by running a temporary docker container against my server so I don't have to worry about what is installed on my host.  First, I define what I need (which you should modify for your purposes):

```
export MYSQL_SERVER_CONTAINER=mysql-db
export MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pswd 
export DB_DOCKER_NETWORK=db-net
export MYSQL_PORT=6604
```

I always create a new docker network which any other containers will need:

```
docker network create --driver bridge $DB_DOCKER_NETWORK
```

Start a mySQL database server:

```
docker run --detach --name=$MYSQL_SERVER_CONTAINER --net=$DB_DOCKER_NETWORK --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -p ${MYSQL_PORT}:3306 mysql
```

Capture IP address of the new server container

```
export DBIP="$(docker inspect ${MYSQL_SERVER_CONTAINER} | grep -i 'ipaddress' | grep -oE '((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])')"
```

Open a command line interface to the server:

```
docker run -it -v ${HOST_DATA}:/data --net=$DB_DOCKER_NETWORK --link ${MYSQL_SERVER_CONTAINER}:mysql --rm mysql sh -c "exec mysql -h${DBIP} -uroot -p"
```

This last container will remove itself when you exit the mySQL interface, while the server will continue running.  You can also share a volume between the server and host to make it easier to import data or scripts. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

```
mysql -u root -P 4406 -h localhost --protocol=tcp -p
```

Remember to change the user, port and host so that it matches your configurations. The -p flag is required if your database user is configured with a password

Answer (score 3):

For conversion，you can create  `~/.my.cnf` file in host:

```
[Mysql]
user=root
password=yourpass
host=127.0.0.1
port=3306
```

Then next time just run `mysql` for mysql client to open connection.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to connect mysql server 5.7 running on my host using the below command:

```
mysql -h 10.10.1.7 -P 3307 --protocol=tcp -u root -p
```

where the ip given is my host ip and 3307 is the port forwaded in mysql docker. After entering the command type the password for mysql. That is it. Now you are connected the mysql docker container from the your host machine.

Answer (score 2):

First, see the logs Are there any errors or not.

```
docker ps -a
docker logs container_name
```

If there is any error, search for the solution of that particular error, if there are no errors you may proceed to the next step.

Remember after starting your container MySQL take a few minutes to start so run those commands after 3-4 minutes.

```
docker exec -it container_name bash
# ONCE YOU ARE INSIDE CONTAINER 
mysql -u root -p
SHOW DATABASES;
exit
```

To connect from terminal or command prompt

```
mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root -p
```

Answer (score 1):

run following command to run container

```
docker run --name db_name -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=PASS--publish 8306:3306 db_name
```

run this command to get mysql db in host machine

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 8306 -uroot  -pPASS
```

in your case it is

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 12345 -uroot  -pPASS
```

Comment: This only works if you use 127.0.0.1 as the address. If you use the host's non-local address you need to add the `--protocol=tcp` flag as described in several other comments/answers. In my case it was extra confusing because I had a local, non-dockerized, mysql instance running as well. By default, even when the port is specified, even if the port is incorrect, the 'mysql' command will connect via the socket file to the local instance.

Comment: @Rich so what did you do to solve that problem? Even I'm having similar setup, one MySql running on host and another in docker container.

Comment: @NITHINRAJT there are 2 ways to accomplish this AFTER you make sure your docker instance isn't listening on the same port (e.g., like in this answer, 8306). (1) Try this answer, the one we're commenting on (e.g., connecting to 127.0.0.1.      (2) Try the next answer - `mysql -u root -P <EXPOSED_DOCKER_PORT_HERE> -h <YOUR_HOST_IP_ADDRESS_HERE> --protocol=tcp -p`. The flag, `--protocol=tcp` is the key to making this work.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the same thing, and I was facing same problem, but I have noticed one thing, whenever I was trying to run docker container with /bin/bash like as below:

`docker container run -it --name test_mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest /bin/bash`

After hitting the above command, my container getting start but facing the same error" ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"

Now, I have tried instead of above command, I have used below command:

`docker container run -itd --name test_mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest`

`docker container exec test_mysql /bin/bash`

then using the command

`mysql -uroot -P3306 -p`

then able to connect, Hope This idea will work in your case.

Thanks
Love Arora

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers worked for me running on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS but I finally cobbled together a way to get connected.

First of all, I followed the docs to get the Docker Container running MySql 8.1 Enterprise server [at this official MySql link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/docker-mysql-getting-started.html).

Next, I had to create a new container like the following to expose MySql:

`docker run --name=mysql1 -p 3306:3306 -d container-registry.oracle.com/mysql/enterprise-server:8.1`

I discovered this command here in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55751353/docker-failed-to-connect-to-mysql-instance-how-to-solve-it).

After that when I ran the command `$ sudo docker container list` I saw something like the following:

> e733323573   container-registry.oracle.com/mysql/enterprise-server:8.1
> "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   23 hours ago   Up 6 hours
> **0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, :::3306->3306/tcp, 33060-33061/tcp**   mysql1

The emphasis is on the bold part, because before that the ports didn't show up.

I assumed this meant that MySql was exposed me via 0.0.0.0:3306 or 127.0.0.1:3306 because that was what everyone was saying.

However, I discovered (very painfully ala trial & error) that this wasn't true.

I then discovered the next part I needed on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101243/error-1130-hy000-host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server).

I needed to allow the "outer" IP Address to MySql which is running in the Docker instance.

1. So I started up the Docker instance.
2. Logged into MySql as root.
3. `SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'root';`

When you run the select command you'll probably see something like the following:

```
+------------+
| host       |
+------------+
| localhost  |
+------------+
```

That means that a user named root, coming from 127.0.0.1 will be able to log in.

However, in our case my ASP.NET Core 6.x WebAPI will be attempting to access the Docker Container from a different address.

**How Can You See The Docker Container Address?**
`$ sudo docker inspect <your-docker-instance-name>`
In the case of the one above we will run the following:

`$ sudo docker inspect mysql1`

When that runs you will see some JSON that contains something like the following:

```
"Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
"GlobalIPv6Address": "",
"GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
"IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
"IPPrefixLen": 16,
"IPv6Gateway": "",
```

The Gateway address is actually the one you want to add to your MySql user table so that a user from outside the Docker container can connect.

So, once you're logged into MySql in the Docker container as root, you can do the following (the password between single-quotes will be your password, of course):

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'172.17.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'172.17.0.1';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If you do that initial query again, you should now see:

```
+------------+
| host       |
+------------+
| 172.17.0.1 |
| localhost  |
+------------+
```

Now, you can create a proper connection string using the ip address (not the Gateway address) from above and it "should" work.

`Server=172.17.0.2;Database=<your-db-name>;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=some-pass;SslMode=preferred;`

So, what you've done is allowed traffic from the Gateway address (      172.17.0.1) to connect to MySql and you've connected to MySql by connecting to the Ip Address (172.17.0.2) of MySql Docker Container.

That's it.  It finally all worked.

**If It Still Doesn't Allow Access**

If you still can't get connected you can try opening up all access (all ip addresses on all DBs & Tables):

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the photos, go to the project -> MySQL -> inspect tab in the docker desktop app and modify the information about the database `.env` file.

`.env` file example:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=0.0.0.0:3306
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testdb
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that your MSQL on container has user access, not just for localhost.

vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
change bind-address  for  = 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Im using docker image 5.7.41 (latest from docker hub) 
after tried few solutions above but it did not work for me so I tried to check current mysql user. then I updated user info. These are my steps:

```
docker exec -it msql57 bash
mysql -u root -p
Enter:
```

---

select your current host and user:

```
mysql> select host,user from mysql.user;
+-----------+---------------+
| host      | user          |
+-----------+---------------+
| localhost | healthchecker |
| localhost | mysql.session |
| localhost | mysql.sys     |
| localhost | root          |
+-----------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
---------
```

update root user:

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET host='%' WHERE user='root';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

quit docker terminal env. now u can connect by command:

```
mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root -p
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

In case this will help somebody:

**My prefered solution**

add ~/.my.cnf with contents

```
[client]
user=<yourusername>
password=typethepasswordhere
host=127.0.0.1
port=3306
```

then from the terminal run `>$ mysql` and you should get in your sql cmd.

**The hardcore alternative**

you can also connect like this

```
docker exec -it containername mysql
```

To get into the sql cmd

or

```
docker exec -it contaiinername bash (or sh)
```

to connect in the container and then run `>$ mysql`

Comment: The question says they want to connect from the host, not from within the container.

Answer (score -8):

change "localhost" to your real con ip addr
because it's to mysql_connect()