# Not able to log in to Docker MySQL from host machine using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, docker

I wish to run PHP code on the host machine which makes a connection to a MySQL (containerized using Docker) database. But I am getting the following error:

**Connection failed: MySQL server has gone away**

On the host machine(Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) I have the following software installed:

PHP 7.2.10 (Non-Docker)
MySQL 8.0.13 (Docker)
Apache 2.5.29 (Non-Docker)

I am using the following connection string in the program on the host machine:

```
<?php
 $connection=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','vernemq','xyzw','some_db');
 if (!$connection) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Note: The above program is written in a PHP file which is located in directory /var/www/html

For understanding let's say the host machine has the IP address 172.10.10.15.

When running this same program with a LAMPP server on a different machine (IP address: 172.10.10.16) on the same network as that of the host, I am able to connect to the MySQL server. I am running the following modified program on the different machine:

```
<?php
 $connection=mysqli_connect('172.10.10.15','vernemq','xyzw','some_db');
 if (!$connection) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

I am even able to connect to the Dockerized MySQL server on the host machine by running the following command on the command prompt of the host machine:

```
$mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u vernemq -p
```

Running the following command from the MySQL prompt returns the following:

```
mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user
    -> ;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| root             | %         |
| vernemq          | %         |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
| vernemq          | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
```

Any pointer on what could be wrong?

**Update** 04/01/2019
I noted following things

When I ran the db connection file from the command line, I got the following error.

```
Getting following error when running the php file from the command prompt
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): Unexpected server respose while doing caching_sha2 auth: 109 in /var/www/html/db.php on line 2
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in /var/www/html/db.php on line 2
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in /var/www/html/db.php on line 2
Connection failed: MySQL server has gone away
```

For this I changed the User authentication method from mysql_native to caching_sha2 with following command

```
ALTER USER 'vernemq' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'vernemq';
```

And it started working.

But I don't want to use caching_sha2 authentication because it breaks another programs that were working with native_mysql authentication method. What is the way out?

Comment: Try commenting out the bind address (server config) and restarting your mysql server.

Comment: How are you trying to connect?  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001750/connect-to-mysql-in-a-docker-container-from-the-host

Comment: As I have mentioned, I am not facing any issue in connecting to mysql docker from the host machine command prompt. Problem is coming when I do it programmatically  through PHP.

Comment: Sorry, try and include all connection strings and your OS/environment information.

Comment: There is ongoing work on this here: https://github.com/vernemq/vernemq/issues/930. Feel free to comment there too!

Comment: Actually, password hash format compatibility is already implemented and merged into master. It will be part of the next release. See https://github.com/vernemq/vernemq/pull/1023 on how to configure it. (You'll need to build master yourself to have access to this feature)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're running on Mac OS and Docker for Mac doesn't provide the `docker0` interface, so you need to create a network alias:

`sudo sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 10.10.0.10/24`

After that try to use the connection string `10.10.0.10:3306`, it should work.

Comment: No, I am not running on Mac OS. My host machine is Ubuntu 18.04 Server Machine.