# Docker - Failed to Connect to MySQL instance. How to solve it?

Tags: mysql, docker, phpstorm

Running in a MAC OS.

Following these [Basic Steps for MySQL Server Deployment with Docker](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.5/en/docker-mysql-getting-started.html), I am trying to make connection with the container trough the php storm database.

And I am getting the error below in the picture:

[image]

I can get access to it trough the terminal:

```
docker exec -it 0ed bash
bash-4.2# mysql -uroot -pdockerLocal
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 47
Server version: 5.7.25 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| testdb             |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

There is no process running in the port 3306.`netstat -vanp tcp | grep 3306` shows nothing.

And my Laravel can't connect to the db server neither.

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testdb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=dockerLocal
```

This is the container info:

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                 NAMES
0edce223c684        mysql/mysql-server:5.7   "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   34 minutes ago      Up 34 minutes (healthy)   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   stupefied_johnson
```

How could I test this connection and how could I have the phpstorm db connection working?

### UPDATE

After the port is exposed (with was the issue) we can't connect to the container using `root@localhost`.

```
SELECT host, user FROM mysql.user;
+-----------+---------------+
| host      | user          |
+-----------+---------------+
| localhost | healthchecker |
| localhost | mysql.session |
| localhost | mysql.sys     |
| localhost | root          |
+-----------+---------------+
```

This is the error :

```
Connection to @0.0.0.0 failed.
            [HY000][1130] null,  message from server: "Host '172.17.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
```

The solution is here in this [post](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/275).

> Check if the database user exists and can connect
>
> In MySQL, each database user is defined with IP address in it, so you can have for example a root user allowed to connect from localhost (127.0.0.1) but not from other IP addresses. With a container, you never access to the database from 127.0.0.1, it could explain the problem.

In short it works if I do like this:

```
CREATE USER 'jerry'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'jerrypassword';
SELECT host, user FROM mysql.user;
+-----------+---------------+
| host      | user          |
+-----------+---------------+
| %         | jerry         |
| localhost | healthchecker |
| localhost | mysql.session |
| localhost | mysql.sys     |
| localhost | root          |
+-----------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bind your container port to your host.

Instead of doing

```
docker run --name=mysql1 -d mysql/mysql-server:tag
```

Do

```
docker run --name=mysql1 -p 3306:3306 -d mysql/mysql-server:tag
```

This binds port 3306 of the container to port 3306 on 127.0.0.1 of the host machine.

You will then be able to connect via `localhost:3306`

Reference : [Docker Run -- Publish or expose port (-p, --expose)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose)

Comment: Hi Justin, you are wright. Now the port is exposed `0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp`