# What is -proot in the following command?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 23306 --user root -proot
```

I have no idea was `-proot` is and I cannot find it in any documentation.

I am following the following instructions on how to set up a docker container with my SQL:
[Connect to mysql in a docker container from the host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001750/connect-to-mysql-in-a-docker-container-from-the-host)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password) used is actually `root`.

It's the same as:

`mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 23306 --user root --password=root`

Comment: Why TF is there nothing in the documentation, where did you come up with this? This has got to be one of the least documented databases to date, I dont know why anyone uses it.

Comment: @chargingBrontosaurus it **is** described in the mysql cli documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password

Comment: @Shadow no its not, Ctrl-F and try to find 'proot'

Comment: @chargingBrontosaurus you cannot seriously expect a documentation to list all possible passwords, can you?