# Hack, HHVM, MySQL: cancelling while connecting

Tags: mysql, connection, cancellation, hhvm, hacklang

If I connect to my MySQL-database via Hack I get an AsyncMysqlConnectException with the message "Error executing AsyncMysql operation: Cancelled".

I use AsyncMysqlConnectionPool::connect with 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0' as $host and 3306 as $port. All three calls with the three different hosts fail.

I run HHVM in a container from an image which I built with a Dockerfile.

FROM hhvm/hhvm:latest

RUN rm -rf /project

ADD . /project

EXPOSE 3306

In the container, I run some commands additionally.

apt-get install -y mysql-server

/etc/init.d/mysql start

I'm expecting to get an AsyncMysqlConnection or an other message for at least one of the three calls.
Where could the problem be? Why doesn't it connect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to mysql in a docker container from the host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001750/connect-to-mysql-in-a-docker-container-from-the-host)

Comment: No, this doesn't.

Comment: Do you know the answer, @billf?